# money-rails monetize :price_cents doesn't return money object for price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

I have an active record model called Record (representing a physical vinyl record) and I'm trying to make use of [money/rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) which uses [rubymoney/monetize](https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize)

I've followed the instructions in money/rails which tells me to utilize a model class method "monetize :attribute_name_cents" and then address it with attribute_name, however when I run my application marketplace_price is nil.  I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here. I'm certain the gem is loaded, and being used. I'm certain that it's providing a sans _cents method automagically yet it is nil and not a Money object as expected. What am I missing?

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :wantlist
   monetize :marketplace_price_cents, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Comment: Have you created a migration and added the `marketplace_price_cents` field to `Record` table?

Comment: Yes, however the table is named records and not Record? Is this the problem? I don't think it is the problem.

Comment: heres what the schema.rb looks like for the records table http://imgur.com/W7wzNhb

Comment: `schema.rb` looks good to me. Don't have other ideas at the moment.

Comment: Hey it's a bit old, but I ran into same problem, configuration all good (I use money-rails on many proects), but on this one not generating method... this is only project thou that uses active-admin gem.... are you using it also ? sry don;t have enought time to go thourgh to find out myself, just asking :)